# rm command and regular expressions via Linux BASH shell

Tags: linux, regex

I am attempting to use regular expressions to remove set of files however the bash shell returns the message

```
rm: cannot remove `[0-99]+ -': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `[a-zA-Z': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `]+.[a-z]+': No such file or directory
```

The command is `[0-99]+\ - [a-zA-Z ]+\.[a-z]+`

**Questions**

1. Can I use regular expressions?
2. If yes, how do I use them with commands such as `rm`, `mkdir`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash (and the other Unix shells) use [wildcards](https://web.archive.org/web/20120828144055/http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html), not full regular expressions, and ranges cannot include a space.

Comment: What can I use with full support for regular expressions?

Comment: You'll have to use find if you want full regex support.  But be aware that find supports several variations on regex.  The default is emacs-style.  If you'd like one of the others, e.g., posix-awk or posix-egrep, you'll need to specify the -regextype.  You can paste the output of find back onto the command line as arguments to rm using `\`...\`` command substitution (but not if the filenames contain spaces).

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Luis.  I've fixed the dead link, replacing it with a link to a snapshot at archive.org.

Answer (score 1):

Use regural expression into a `find` command like

`find . -type f -regex regEXP`

and use it in tandem with `rm` in the following way

`find . -type f -regex regEXP -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: Careful: `-regexp` matches the whole path (different from `-name`), including parent directories. Not an issue with these patterns, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: Yes you're right but this command works

Comment: @DonCallisto: You missed a hyphen on the `rf`. If GNU find is available it's quicker to delete with the `-delete` command.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - What do you mean by `whole path`?

Comment: By "whole path", he means everything including the "./" that will get pasted onto the beginning of each result.